# How do I get my neovim settings to work properly and actually save

Tags: config, neovim, code-editor

I just installed nvim for the first time, this is also my first time using a terminal based code editor, and I'm migrating from VSCode (ik it's going to be hard),
and now I'm configuring it, I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdn_pKJUda8&t=347s&ab_channel=JoseanMartinez

And when put the code in the options.lua file, it does not do anything, for example, the

`opt.relativenumber = true`

is not doing anything

I have tried running commands to change settings, and that has worked, for example

`:set relativenumber`

But as soon as I exit the file and open a new one, it just breaks again

I have tried simply copy and pasting the code, restarting nvim, switching terminal emulators, etc.

It's really annoying because I am trying to get rid of this stupid feature where it continues comments to the next line and I have to run like 50 commands every time I open a new file just so I can edit it the way I want

My .config file is in

`C:\Users\brady\.config`

and my nvim.exe file is in

`C:\Users\brady\nvim-win64\bin`

I am on Windows 10 and my terminal emulator is called 'Tabby'

Comment: Where, specifically, in `C:\Users\brady\.config`? “.config file” sounds like the file is named `.config`, but `.config\nvim` should be a folder for NeoVim configuration (and the tutorial doesn’t show the options.lua file being put *directly* in there either, instead going to `lua/josean/core`).

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ry- yes, in my .config i have a nvim folder and then all the files mentioned in the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! All the tutorials I am watching are on Linux, but I am on Windows. So instead of putting the nvim folder in my .config, I am supposed to put it in C:\Users\brady\AppData\Local

Comment: Glad to hear, that you found the issue! Please don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're adding your nvim-config file in the correct directory? I'd assume that you need to add your `init.vim` into `C:\Users\brady\.config\nvim\init.vim`.

Maybe [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28040/31844) helps you.

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure it is, but when I search it up it does not appear, even though I even copied the file path directly from the directory

Comment: Could you please upload your file structure?